# Sending mail with sendmail - not sending

Tags: php, email, apache-2.4, smtp, sendmail

I have apache2.4 web server with PHP on Debian server.

I noticed that my PHP mail() function doesn't send any mail. Looked at the spam folder as well.

I cleared all the mail logs on my server and tried to run the following command:

```
root@myvps:/usr/sbin# echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v "myemail@gmail.com"
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <root>.
```

and through the command I still don't get any email, as well as empty logs:

[image]

Any idea why sendmail command and mail through php mail() don't actually send emails?

Comment: Have you inspected web server (php) log files?

Comment: I wrote that I'm trying to send mail via the command, so it's irrelevant. and yes I did - no errors from PHP side.